# Installation of JX3 with Terraform on EKS does not auto populate secrets

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, jenkins-x, jenkins-x-3

I installed JX3 on EKS using terraform using the instructions in their documentation. However none of the secrets are being auto populated. jx admin logs shows the following:

error: failed to find hmac token from secret: could not find lighthouse hmac token lighthouse-hmac-token in namespace jx: secrets "lighthouse-hmac-token" not found

The secrets are stored in vault

Can someone please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay this issue happens only on Kubernetes 1.21 on EKS. I downgraded to 1.20 and the issue was fixed

Comment: what do you mean to downgrading 1.21 to 1.21 ?

Comment: 1.20. Apologies